# Software Design in Software Projects

Tags: uml, software-design

Typically in a software project, which individual is responsible in creating the UML Diagrams. I.E. Sequence , Component, Use Case Diagrams. Is it the System Analyst?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about assigning responsibilities in a certain organizational structure, not about coding. Perhaps this question would be more appropriate at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system analyst would create functional/conceptual UML diagrams (domain model, use case diagrams, ...).

The software architect / designer would create technical UML diagrams (component diagrams, deployment diagram, ...).

Most UML diagram types can be used in creating functional models as well as in creating technical models. For example, the classes in a class diagram can represent business entities, but also classes in an OO programming language, or tables in a database.

For more information, see [Which UML models should we make?](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/WhichUMLmodels.pdf)